# Firebase push notification cloud messaging how to access Additional Data as Notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

[image]

I just want to access those Custom data written inside additional option on click action

```
    private void showNotification(String title, String message,String category,String index) {
     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);break;    
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
     b.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     notificationManager.notify(1,b.build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it by myself for others if they are having same problem then this is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution my own to others if they are having same problem you can use this function

.getData();